# Adding a number to a already present variable sed/grep/awk

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have this in file.txt

> FORM: lookupfile
>   Version: 1
>   LookupFile:"$i"

How can I find this in the file and add a variable `b` to the `$i`.

So example

**INPUT**

> FORM: lookupfile
>   Version: 1
>   LookupFile:4

Suppose my b=300

**OUTPUT**

> FORM: lookupfile
>   Version: 1
>   LookupFile:304

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -v b=$b 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} /LookupFile/ {print $1,$2+300;next} {print}' file.txt
```

Here's another one, with `sed`:

`num=$(sed -n '/LookupFile:.*/p' file.txt | cut -d':' -f2); substitute=$(expr 300 +  $num ); sed "s/LookupFile:.*/LookupFile:$substitute/g" file.txt`

If you want to make sed do changes inside the file, use the `-i` flag with the last sed command

Comment: And the other lines?

Comment: Also the field separator is missing: `awk -v b=$b -F: '/LookupFile/ {print $1":"$2+b; next} {print}' file.txt`

Comment: Yeah, the `:` is missing. Your command works kos. Thank you!

Comment: Guys, its tough to do everything from memory on mobile.  Can somebody edit that plz ?

Comment: Can't `awk` write directly to the file? Like for example `sed` has `-i`.

Comment: @SamFlynn I know that GNU `awk` can: `gawk -i inplace -v b=$b -F: '/LookupFile/ {print $1":"$2+b; next} {print}' file.txt`

Comment: Yup but if you call just awk, it's a sym link to whatever is installed by default.  For instance my 14.04 came with mawk if I'm not mistaken. Gawk had to be installed.  With other versions of awk you have to redirect output to temp file , then from temp file back to original

Comment: @kos I think what would be even simpler is BEGIN { FS=OFS=":" }

Comment: Hmmm nope it's not gonna work since if you assign `:` to OFS then `:` is going to be printed also after `$2`, invalidating `$2+b`

Comment: @kos there's only 2 fields there. After that it's a new record.  : should not be printed after $2 .

Comment: Yeah you're right, that makes sense. Updated. Why do you think it's better by the way?

Comment: You ca just use print instead of print $1, etc

Comment: Added sed version, please check

Answer (score 3):

```
awk  -v b=$b -F: '{ if ( $1 == "LookupFile" ) $0=$1":"($2+b); print $0 }' file.txt
```

This will print all the line and will change the line only when $1 is "LookupFile" string. Delimiter is ":"

Comment: It should print the sum of `$b` and the current value (4)

Comment: Now changed to add sum

Answer (score 1):

Using `gawk`

```
b=300; gawk -v "b=$b" '/^LookupFile/ {line=gensub (/(^LookupFile:.*)[0-9]+/,"\\1",$0); number=gensub(/^LookupFile:([0-9]+)/,"\\1",$0); printf "%s",line; printf "%s",number+b"\n"} !/^LookupFile/ {print}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
FORM: lookupfile
Version: 1
LookupFile:4

$ b=300; gawk -v "b=$b" '/^LookupFile/ {line=gensub (/(^LookupFile:.*)[0-9]+/,"\\1",$0); number=gensub(/^LookupFile:([0-9]+)/,"\\1",$0); printf "%s",line; printf "%s",number+b"\n"} !/^LookupFile/ {print}' foo
FORM: lookupfile
Version: 1
LookupFile:304
```

Comment: Which version of `awk` are you using? It gives me `awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,` twice

Comment: @kos `gawk` o_O

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pe "s/^(LookupFile:)(.*)/\$1.($b+\$2)/e" file.txt
```